# Java - Utility to Store files on Disk?

Tags: java, file, io, local-storage, utility

As a part of my application, I need to store files on disk - followed by calling Lucene to add these to its index to enable search.

Ofcourse, java provides default APIs to write and retrieve files from disk, but being an experienced programmer, I am imagining upfront that I would be re-inventing the wheel to manage details like encoding, ACID, etc etc.

In short, I am looking for a proven API (open source / freeware) which I could use / plugin to my app - to store /retrieve files from disk.

Files compression is not my primary requirement.

Please advice.

DK

Comment: Good question, but... Any more specific requirements? Some on-disk databases can store arbitrary data. Does it really have to be "real files"?

Comment: Hmm.. I guess it would be worth to mention here that I am looking forward to host this application on the cloud (ideally PaaS - and not IaaS) in other words, my choice of technologies would be limited to the ones that are provided by the Cloud platform. Moreover, given that I am not aware of any of such disk based DBs (= I need to learn afresh), I was thinking of just using a utility to store files to disk. Given that even the databases would eventually be storing files on the disk itself, there is no extra advantage that I would get - isnt it ? (please do correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: That's actually a good project if it exists, or to initiate if it doesn't... Is this Java 7 BTW?

Comment: I would be surprised if there isnt one already.. I am working with Java 6 for now.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud APIs are dependent on the cloud. Which cloud do you plan to use?
E.g.

- for Google Cloud Storage you have an Java API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/
- but you can also use the Datastore API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/
- and/or Memcache (for in-memory caching): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/

Amazon has a Java API to many of their services: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/

You should select your Cloud type/provider first, and study their API.

Comment: So the suggestion is to rely on cloud based implementations and not use any utility jar. Wouldnt this bind my solution to a particular cloud implementation ? I would prefer a custom utility jar (as in the original question) which provides me with a standard java.io implementation, however havent been able to find one yet...

Comment: Yes, you would be cloud-locked, but the dependency is fairly minimal. Since cloud services and infrastructure is valuable and saves you enormous amount of work, choose a cloud wisely, then use the API heavily. This is what I suggest.

If you are creating a custom product for yourself this is usually the best way to go - best ROI.

Unless your business needs you to create a product that is viable in any cloud, do not target that as a first step. Hack your first version first, and if needed, you can abstract away over time, if you consider moving another cloud.

Good luck! :-)